# Are any files loaded when a terminal session terminates?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, exit

I know that .profile / .bash_profile are loaded when a terminal session is started, either through local machine or SSH. Are there any files that are loaded/called when the session terminates?

Reason:
I have the .profile set to log the date and IP address that connects to a terminal session for a specific user.

Comment: You're aware of wtmp/`last`, right?

Comment: Rahul's answer is a good and valid one but I think the only foolproof way to do this is via an independent process, ie, a daemon that monitors current logins perhaps via wtmp or `w` or whatever interface you can find available in whatever language you do that in.

Comment: @derobert, as I stated in a comment below, I'm already getting the login info from the `$SSH_CLIENT` variable, I just wanted to know if there were any files that were executed when a session terminated. @goldilocks, I'm no where near experienced or versed enough with any language to do that yet. What I have now, thanks to Rahul, will be perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @Morph It sounds like you're trying to build a log of user logins/logouts & IP address (at least for one specific user). That's what wtmp/last already is. That's why I want to be sure you're aware of it, as it sounds like you're reinventing the wheel. And if you need something slightly different, you may want to look at how it works (PAM) and see if you can just customize it.

Comment: @derobert, that would be an accurate description, however, it's more like reinventing it without knowing it already existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.bash_logout` executed by bash when login shell exits. but you can also get IP address and date details using `lastlog` , did your try that ?

`~/.bash_logout` , but it will not run when session `kill -9 $$` or may be close forcefully

Comment: There's no way around the `kill -9`, or stuff like "someone just cut the power" but a normal logout will not do that. +1

Comment: I was just googling around about this and also beware that closing an X terminal emulator sends SIGHUP to the shell, and `~/.bash_logout` will not run :(  So it is a SIGTERM only event (eg, you use `exit`).

Comment: I'm using `echo "${SSH_CLIENT%% *}"` to get the IP address already.

All connections are done through SSH to an offshore server. So cutting power isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

All shells have a way to run some code when the shell exits: a trap. “Trap” is the shell word for [signal handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal). You can set a trap for a signal by listing its name (`INT`, `HUP`, …) or its number, or use the special value `0` or `EXIT` for when the shell exits normally (by reaching the end of the input or if `exit` was called).

```
trap 'echo "$IP_ADDRESS logged out at $(date)" >>"$LOG_FILE"' EXIT HUP INT TERM
```

You can't trap `kill -KILL` or power failures.

I doubt that what you're doing is actually useful. This information is already recorded in the system logs. It's even more reliable there, because you get an entry for `kill -KILL` too. The command `last` shows the start date, end date and origin (terminal or IP address) for all past and current sessions since the last log rotation.

Comment: As I said before, I didn't know last existed. I'm not very versed in shell/bash. So like derobert said, it's like I was reinventing the wheel without knowing the wheel already existed.